# Click is being fired during foreach, but not after rendering is finished

Tags: knockout.js

Here's a jsfiddle of what is happening.

This isnt the action im looking for.

I want it so that after the table is rendered and a user clicks on the tr the information should be displayed...

Info should not be called during the rendering.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
http://jsfiddle.net/yG6Tg/2/

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'showInfo';
Bindings value: attr:{code: code}, click:$parent.showInfo($data) knockout-2.1.0.js:48`

Comment: Sorry i didn't save the jsfiddle properly, it has been fixed to what i meant to post, the issue stil persists

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out.

Since I had :

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: venue">
    <tr data-bind="click:$parent.info($data)">
```

It was automatically calling that event. I realize now that I don't need to pass the data manually as 'this' will be bound to the data with the function itself. The following is solution:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: venue">
        <tr data-bind="click:$parent.info"> 

info = function() {alert(this.name);}
```

Comment: Also `$data` is passed as the first parameter. This is the supported way of getting at it.  `info = function(data) {alert(data.name);}`